# How can I check if a number input is not empty?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, validation, html-input

I have this input field in a form which I validate using spring boot validator:

```
<input class="form-control" th:field="*{numericField}"
    type="number" min="0" id="numeric_field_input">
```

The valid range is all positive numbers. But even if I do not fill in any number, the field validates. I believe the default value is zero. Adding something like

```
th:default="-1"
```

did not solve the problem. How can I check on serverside that a user input any value?

These are my current annotations of the field:

```
   @Positive(message = "{validation.numericField.positive}")
   @ColumnDefault("0")
   private Integer numericField;
```

Comment: check if there is a value. -1 is a numeric value, so that could be a valid input. If you're checking in Java, and you are working with objects, you can do a null check

Comment: How can I check using the validation annotations or what do I need to change?

Comment: is it tomcat? because I remember tomcat had some old issue regarding not dealing properly with null numeric values (I can't remember exactly what it is, but I remember it was many years ago) that was fixed adding some magic key-value pair in the server jvm configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 validations

```
@NotNull("message": "numericField: positive number value is required")

@Min(value=0, message="numericField: positive number, min 0 is required")
```

Comment: Awesome! I used @NotEmpty which only works for Strings. @NotNull is correct. Maybe you want to change your post to: `@NotNull(message="numericField: positive number value is required")
` That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min` constraint to limit values be only positive numbers

```
//import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

@Min(value = 0, message = "numericField not be negative")
 private Integer numericField;
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's ultimate solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> This is the final way how [sic] I fixed it:
>
> ```
> @NotNull(message = "{validation.numericField.positive}")
> @Positive(message = "{validation.numericField.positive}")
> private Integer numericField;
> ```